# How to get data of firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from my deep hierarchy database

[image: My database' hierarchy]

this is my latest code

```
this.planRef = this.db.object('user/buku1/belanja/'+ id);
return this.planRef;
```

Comment: Suggest you to use https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: @GCSDC how to get data from object in object?

Comment: Your code isn't reading anything yet. To get started with that, I highly recommend checking out the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return firebase.database().ref('user/buku1/belanja/'+ id)
.once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
      var dataValue = (snapshot.val();
    });
```

you just need follow the Firebase documention.